# Regex, ignore matches that might occur inside a string

Tags: regex, swift, string

Say for example I have the test string:

```
this is text "This is a quote { containing } some characters" blah blah { inside }
```

I would like to match every pair of curly brackets and the text in between using the expression

`\{[^{]*?\}`

but ignore any matches that might occur inside of a string, namely the `{ containing }` portion of the string, or even be able to match only `{ text }` of the following test string

```
more text "text text { { { } " { text } words
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this works:

```
{[^}]*}(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*"[^"]*)*$)
```

But I'm not sure that it's bullet proof. You can view it [online](https://regex101.com/r/xDCSU7/4):

- `{[^}]*}` get the curly content
- `(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*"[^"]*)*$)` ensure that it's followed by an even number of `"`.

**Note:** This regex doesn't take account of escaped double quotes.

Comment: That is some gnarly regex work there. Pretty epic... Think you could explain what each part does in case others wish to reference this question/answer? I mean I know the engine does, but just for convenience.